# Problem with Alexa node modules and Lambda

Tags: javascript, module, aws-lambda, rabbitmq, alexa-skills-kit

I have a queue in CloudRabbitMQ such that with a javascript code I can send an instance there. This is the code:

```js
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

function send(answer){
    // TODO: Log the answer in a database
    console.log(`El color enviado ha sido: ${answer}`);


    //Conectamos con el servidor de RabbitMQ
    amqp.connect('ID OF THE CLOUDRABBITMQ' + '?heartbeat=60', function(error0, connection) {
        if (error0) {
            console.log("Fallo al conectar con CloudRabbitMQ")
            throw (error0);
        }

        console.log("¡La conexión con CloudRabbitMQ ha sido correcta!")

        //Creamos un canal de comunicación 
        connection.createChannel(function(error1, channel) {
            if (error1) {
                throw (error1)
            }

            var queue = 'PiezasTetris';
            var msg = answer;

            channel.sendToQueue(queue, Buffer.from(msg));
            console.log(" [x] Sent %s", msg);
        })

        //Cerramos la conexion
        setTimeout(function() {
            connection.close();
            process.exit(0)
        }, 500);
    });

};
```

The code works well but the problem is that I want this function to send a color to the queue with Alexa calling it. So for example, "Alexa, send the color blue": Alexa will call

> send("blue")

The problem with all this is that the CloudRabbitMQ module ('amqplib') that I am using cant be introduced to the Alexa code. Some pages say that the solution is to use Lambda Functions but I don't know how to implement the Lambda to be called when Alexa wants to send an object:

> Alexa wants to send "Blue" -> ("Blue") to Lambda Function -> Lambda Function calls send("Blue")

So now, I don't know how to create a Lambda Function that will be called when the Alexa Intent receives the color from the user and then the Lambda Function will call the function "send()".

Pls I am very noob at AWS Lambda so if you could explain me the most easy and simple version of this, I would appreciate...

Comment: https://www.serverless.com/blog/node-rest-api-with-serverless-lambda-and-dynamodb/ - skip sections about DynamoDB, this tutorial will help you with deploying lambda function

Comment: That tutorial was absolutely my case!! Thks it helped me to finish the project!!